# merge two lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, built-in

I have two .txt files that one of them (a) contains categories(*,*,A,A,A....) information and the other (b) contains the values.
I need to merge them and split

Thanks for your help!

Comment: d['A'][1] would be the second segment of A, because of zero-based indexing ;)

Comment: you seem to be doing a "groupby" on the labels for the first column to decide the groups of values for the second - is that correct? I can illustrate that in an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the problem, you are parsing the inputs as parallel streams where the first input is labels, the second is values.  I understand that the labels are intended to be *groups* of labels that will mean the results will be *groups* of values on the label/keys.

I gather from the comment that followed you also require mean, count and other information.

For that functionality, I see you can use something like this:

```
import itertools

def accumulator(seriesA,seriesB):
    results = {}
    for a,grouped in itertools.groupby(zip(seriesA,seriesB), key=lambda x:x[0]):
        values = [x[1] for x in grouped]
        count  = len(values)
        mean   = sum(values)/count
        results.setdefault(a, []).append(dict(values=values, count=count, mean=mean))
    return results
```

I tested it locally using your sample data rather than reading files for clarity:

```
# SIMULATE the file reads for this example!
input_A = ['_','_','A','A','A','_','_','B','B','A','A']
input_B = [1.0, 1.264, 20.646, 14.346, 16.645, 327.5, 34.646, 343.97, 12.66, 147.2, 364.5454]
import pprint
pprint.pprint(accumulator(input_A, input_B), width=120)
```

With the results:

```
$ python accumulator.py
{'A': [{'count': 3, 'mean': 17.212333333333333, 'values': [20.646, 14.346, 16.645]},
       {'count': 2, 'mean': 255.87269999999998, 'values': [147.2, 364.5454]}],
 'B': [{'count': 2, 'mean': 178.31500000000003, 'values': [343.97, 12.66]}],
 '_': [{'count': 2, 'mean': 1.1320000000000001, 'values': [1.0, 1.264]},
       {'count': 2, 'mean': 181.073, 'values': [327.5, 34.646]}]}
```

Comment: Thank u so much, this is a very clean and fine answer for me to understand!

Comment: Hi, when I tried this with my own data I am having this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. It seems lile it is about mean   = sum(values)/count calculation

Comment: That is because you need to convert the data in `seriesB` to floats first. You can see it in their second code block: there are no quotation marks around the numbers. To convert a list of strings into a list of floating point numbers with `seriesB = [float(item) for item in seriesB]`

Comment: As @Jasmijn says, you have to convert the incoming file to the right type.  You can do it on the assignment of values `values = [float(x[1]) for x in grouped]` or as part of the loading of the file.

On a different note - if you consider your question answered, you should mark the answer accordingly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something like this:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().split('\n')

def read_data(categories, values):
    parsed_data = {}
    for key, value in zip(read_file(categories), read_file(values)):
        if key not in parsed_data:
            parsed_data[key] = [[value]]
        elif key != previous_key:
            parsed_data[key].append([value])
        else:
            parsed_data[key][-1].append(value)
        previous_key = key
    return parsed_data

print(read_data('categories.txt', 'values.txt'))
```

- I made a convenience function for reading from the files and splitting the lines for some minor code deduplication.
- You don't need to create a list from a `zip` in order to iterate over it.
- I chose to return the dictionary instead of printing it so you can use it in other ways too.

Comment: Hi, this work really best for me thanks for your kind helps. Can I ask one more question how can I add each segment's mean and lengths to segments values like {'values': [20.646,14.346,16.645],'mean':17,2123333333 , 'length': 3}

Comment: For the mean you can `import statistics` and use `statistics.mean` and for the length you can use `len`. If you need more detail than that I would just open a new question on here, there the comments aren't meant for asking and answering separate questions! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def dict4(a, b):
  pairs = list(zip((open(a).read()).split("\n"), (open(b).read().split("\n"))))
  dict1 = dict()
  # Store the key before the current one
  # to detect segments
  key_before = None
  for key,value in pairs:
    # Don't add an empty string as a key
    if key not in dict1 and key != '':
      dict1[key] = list()
      if key != '':
        # Append the new value to the last list
        # in the list that is stored at index key
        # or append a new list with the value
        if key_before == key:
          dict1[key][len(dict1[key])-1].append(value)
        else:
          dict1[key].append([value])
    key_before = key
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am kinda starting to see what I did wrong